# What is Extended Fisher-Kolmogorov (EFK)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is Extended Fisher-Kolmogorov (EFK)?

There are many references to it, but I failed to find what is actually *is*. Is it some kind of non-linear differential equation? Does it describe physical systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be:

It is a nonlinear PDE, usually stated as

$$u_t+\gamma u_{xxxx}-u_{xx}-u+u^3=0 $$

as introduced in Dee & van Sarloos' [paper](http://lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/~saarloos/Papers/PRL_60_2641.pdf). Most authors like to emphasize its application in modeling of phase transitions at critical points.